# Eigenvalues of CPT operator

Tags: cpt-symmetry

> Suppose we define an operator CPT that carries out the CPT transformation:
>   $$\text{CPT}|\Psi\rangle = A|\Psi\rangle$$
>   where A is just a constant. Or put another way, the states of our theory are eigenfunctions of the CPT operator. -[Source](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/390463/198219)

What do the eigenvalues of the CPT operator mean? [*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/390321/clarification-on-cpt-symmetry#comment877141_390463)

Comment: I'm not sure which 'idea' you're referring to here - there's an issue that you're saying e.g. "let $⟨0|$ represent a charge transformation" - this isn't possible as $⟨0|$ is a *state*, not a transformation. In the meantime, I'll have to put this on hold but I think we can edit this down to the actual question you want answered relatively quickly

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 I have updated the post to reflect the feedback given. Apologies for the lack of clarity of this question.. I was just sketching [this image](https://antimatter.at/fileadmin/downloads/cpt_symmetry_detailed_a_01.png) in 3d given the cube configuration above. Then I noticed all the symmetries & translations & it kind of blew my mind! Maybe it's such an obvious thing & I had just not seen it before.. I however still find it interesting that given this setup, I'm not sure it's possible to determine which state was the starting state of the sequence.

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 Perhaps 1 of the 2 results in Google for [quantum CPT transformation](https://www.google.com/search?q="quantum+cpt+transformation") will make some sort of sense to you? Also, reduced question to simplest form.

Comment: Well, it's certainly clear now - the previous version still had a question in there as well and I do think that could be a good question, with a bit of work - in the [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6524647) you originally mentioned - they used e.g. $\left<t_{01}\right| = \left<0\right| + \left<1\right|$ (up to normalisation, anyway), which would be more like $⟨∅|\left(C+P\right)$, while the 'CP transformation' would be more like $⟨∅|CP$ (although I've skipped a couple of things that would need more than a comment to explain), so I'm still not sure which exactly you meant

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 I have not (yet) looked at the paper that the graphic came from. I just found that graphic via Google search (my sketches are rubbish or I would have posted one of them instead). I will do more research & potentially ask that question separately (I need to better understand [Noether's theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03616)).

Comment: Just a note for anyone wondering about whether or not this in on topic - there's CPT symmetry as referred to in QFT and particle physics (neither of which are explicitly covered by this SE), then heavily related is the CPT symmetry of 'PT-symmetric/non-Hermitian quantum theory', which is more like fundamentals of quantum information theory and (I'd certainly argue) is at least relevant from a computational perspective, although people are of course, free to disagree

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 People are not free to disagree: If you single-handedly close and re-open the question, it invalidates previous close votes.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I originally closed it as *unclear*, which it originally was (and this was also what the original close reason was before I closed it). Whether or not it's *off-topic* doesn't have anything to do with it being clear or not and if people feel it's off topic, it can still get close votes - if you in particular feel it should be closed, then I'll have to ask you to take that to meta or flag (as opposed to voting to close) as off-topic. In this specific case, if it reaches 4 close votes, I'll close it because you're unable to and the effect will be the same

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 Close reasons often aren't black and white (just the system enforces that). In any case, I don't feel strongly about this question, but I feel that this single-handed closing (and opening!) by mods is not good practice, though it might make sense given the size of the site.

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 do you know what is meant here exactly by "CPT operator"? Is it just the unitary operation obtained as product of charge, parity, and time translations?

Comment: @glS If I'm remembering right, it's not unitary, but it's the product of the charge, parity and time 'reversal' operations (or at the least, something equivalent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Background - CPT (and $\mathcal{CPT}$) symmetry in QFT

I think the first step in answering is this is explaining what CPT (also, $\mathcal{CPT}$) symmetry from a quantum *computing* perspective is *not*. If this same question on physics SE was asked, I would refer them to chapters 23 and 40 of Srednicki's [*Quantum Field Theory*](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html) for the full-blown explanation. However, while that is useful background for understanding the CPT operation from a computational perspective, the important point is that the Parity $\left(\mathcal P\right)$ and Time $\left(\mathcal T\right)$ reversal transformations are operations that act on the spatial and temporal co-ordinates, giving unitary Parity $\left(P\right)$ and Time $\left(T\right)$ operators on the *field*, as well as additional Charge conjugation operations $\left(\mathcal C\text{ and }C\right)$ and so, may change depending on the particle being looked at/used. Implementing these transformations on a quantum computer would then mean that different 'implementations' of computer could act differently under the $\mathcal C,\, \mathcal P$ and $\mathcal T$ operations, which is not so good.

### $\mathcal{PT}$-symmetric Hamiltonians

*However*, what this *does* lead to is the realisation that Hamiltonians can be non-Hermitian, yet have real eigenvalues due to having $\mathcal{PT}$ symmetry (of the 'reversing the spatial and temporal co-ordinates' sense) as discovered by [Bender and Boettcher](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9712001). This symmetry can be broken (the Hamiltonian has real eigenvalues) or unbroken (the Hamiltonian has complex eigenvalues), with a phase transition (often known as the *exceptional point*) in between. This allows for the definition of $\mathcal P\text{ and }\mathcal T$ ($\mathcal T$ is complex conjugation), as well as the $\mathcal{PT}$ inner product: for a state $\psi\left(x\right)$ and Hamiltonian $H$ with eigenstates $\phi_n\left(x\right)$,

\begin{align}
\mathcal P\left(x, y\right) &= \delta\left(x+y\right) \\ 
&= \sum_n\left(-1\right)^n\phi_n\left(x\right)\phi_n\left(-y\right) \\
\mathcal{PT}\psi\left(x\right) &= \psi^{\mathcal{PT}}\left(x\right)  \\
&= \int dy\, \mathcal P\left(x, y\right)\mathcal T \psi\left(y\right) = \psi^*\left(-x\right) \\
\left\langle\psi|\chi\right\rangle^{\mathcal{PT}} &= \int dx\,\psi^{\mathcal{PT}}\left(x\right)\chi\left(x\right)
\end{align}

As per [Bender, Brody and Jones](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0208076), in the unbroken regime, an operator $\mathcal C$ (resembling the charge conjugation operator in QFT mentioned above) can be defined, as well as the $\mathcal{CPT}$ inner product $\left\langle\psi|\chi\right\rangle^{\mathcal{CPT}}$:

### Eigenvectors of the $\mathcal{CPT}$ operator

In the unbroken phase, the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian are real. As the parity reversal operator has no effect on a number and the time reversal operator is complex conjugation, we have that $\mathcal{PT}E_n\phi_n = E_n\mathcal{PT}\phi_n$ and so, the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian are simultaneously eigenstates of the $\mathcal{PT}$ operator (it's assumed that the eigenvectors are non-degenerate for simplicity, although this breaks down at the exceptional point).

As shown by [Weigert](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306040), we also have the completeness relation $\sum_n\left(-1\right)^n\phi_n\left(x\right)\phi_n\left(y\right) = \delta\left(x-y\right)$.

We also have that $\left(\mathcal{PT}\right)^2\phi_n\left(x\right) = \mathcal{PT}\phi^*_n\left(-x\right) = \phi_n\left(x\right)$, giving eigenvalues $e^{-i\omega_n}$ as $\mathcal Te^{-i\omega_n} = e^{i\omega_n}\mathcal T$. This eigenvalue is absorbed into the definition of the eigenvector so that $\phi_n\left(x\right)\rightarrow e^{-\frac{1}{2}i\omega_n}\phi_n\left(x\right)$ and now $\mathcal{PT}\phi_n\left(x\right) = \phi_n\left(x\right)$.

This gives that $\left\langle\phi_n|\phi_m\right\rangle^{\mathcal{PT}} = \int dx\,\phi_n\left(x\right)\phi_m\left(x\right)$. However, this is not necesarily positive, so we define an additional operator, $\mathcal C$, alongside the $\mathcal{CPT}$ inner product, in order to satisfy the completeness relation:

\begin{align}\mathcal C\left(x, y\right) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \phi_n\left(x\right)\phi_n\left(y\right) \\ 
\mathcal C\phi_n\left(x\right) &= \left(-1\right)^n\phi_n\left(x\right) \\
\psi^{\mathcal{CPT}}\left(x\right) &= \int dy\, \mathcal C\left(x, y\right)\psi^*\left(-y\right) \\
\left\langle\psi|\chi\right\rangle^{\mathcal{CPT}} &= \int dx\,\psi^{\mathcal{CPT}}\left(x\right)\chi\left(x\right)
\end{align}

Computationally, discrete Hamiltonians/systems are more commonly used than continuous ones and helpfully, the above applies in the same/equivalent way to continuous systems (swapping continuous for discrete where applicable) as above.

### The eigenvalues of the $\mathcal{CPT}$ operator

Having defined parity and time reversal operators and a new operator that looks like charge conjugation in order to satisfy the completeness relation, we have the answer of what the eigenvalue of the $\mathcal{CPT}$ operator is already written down: $$\mathcal{CPT}\phi_n\left(x\right) = \left(-1\right)^n\phi_n\left(x\right),$$ where $\phi_n$ is an eigenstate of both the $\mathcal{CPT}$ operator and some $\mathcal{PT}$-symmetric Hamiltonian.

But what do these eigenvalues *mean*?

- As per the [linked answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/390463/114272), it's analogous to the result in QFT where the eigenstates of the system are invariant under $\mathcal{CPT}$ reversal
- The Hamiltonian is in the *unbroken* regime (that is, it has real eigenvalues)
- As such, the eigenbasis is *complete*
- the eigenvectors corresponding to the $-1$ eigenvalues have a *negative* $\mathcal{PT}$ inner product
- Which feels similar to the notions of positive and negative charge of e.g. positrons and electrons, only, it's not that
- Not much else, really

Comment: In the PT set of equations third line, x is not in the RHS. The free variables on both sides don't match.

Comment: @AHusain whoops - fixed now, at least down to normal abuses of notation